# Google Apps Script : Fuzzy match in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to match an array of phone numbers (A) to another array which is a list of excluded phone numbers (B). If a match is found, I want to remove those phone numbers from array A. However, the issue is that the phone numbers are not mentioned exactly in same format in both the arrays. Therefore it becomes a case of fuzzy match. How do I apply fuzzy match in google script? See example below of 2 arrays :

```
  var A = ['1-513-317-7948','513-235-5403','792-3900','1-800-752-2339', '513-234-2323'];
  var B = ['513-317-7948','1-513-235-5403','792-3900','1-800-752-2339'];
```

Comment: Define the format with [regex](https://regex101.com/). Hint : `d-ddd-ddd-dddd` and so on.Then match the format and the value.

Comment: The comparison between these `arrays` will give you an empty `array`.

Answer (score 0):

@Op, can you please update the question with expected output and what are the code snippets you have tried so far?

I am assuming that you want to check if they have same phone number sequences. (1-513-317-7948 and 513-317-7948 are same).

When you are comparing two phone numbers, you can remove the '-' in the phone numbers and check whether it has same number sequences.

You can do some thing like this. Hope this helps.

```js
var A = [
  "1-513-317-7948",
  "513-235-5403",
  "792-3900",
  "1-800-752-2339",
  "513-234-2323",
];
var B = ["513-317-7948", "1-513-235-5403", "792-3900", "1-800-752-2339"];

const isSame = (str1, str2) => {
  const phone1 = str1.replace(/-/g, "");
  const phone2 = str2.replace(/-/g, "");
  return phone1.includes(phone2) || phone2.includes(phone1);
};
const output = A.filter((ph1) => !B.some((ph2) => isSame(ph1, ph2)));

console.log(output);
```